# Can't install HP Deskjet D1530 printer using OS: Windows 7 x64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, printer

I need some help installing this HP Deskjet D1530 printer on my Windows 7 x64 bit operating system. When I run the start up disk it says it's not compatible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would say is that I never install drivers from the CD/DVD that comes with a product. I ALWAYS check to make sure I have the latest from the manufacturer's web site.

The link for your product is here:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=al-76327-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=3568420&sw_lang=

Go download it and give that a shot. It lists 64-bit Windows 7 as supported so it should work.